# Use Editorial Calendar on any other page within any other plugin

Tags: plugins

I want to show Editorial Calendar on my custom plugin's page,
so how to do that?

Plugin available on
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/editorial-calendar

Now I tried to include edcal.php (plugin page) but its showing me `Cannot redeclare class EdCal in` due to two time declaration of that class, so now hot to display same plugin page on my page?

I tried `include(  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ). 'edcal.php');`

Comment: Show us what you have tried, where we can find this plugin, where the docs are. See also [ask].

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to wordpress so I cant explain much...

Comment: @toscho in sort I want to display post in calendar format,so if you can suggest any other things then its very useful for me.but I want to use this calendar on my custom page so please suggest according any